# How to find directories (not) containing a certain file efficiently

Tags: shell, find, directory

I need to list all directories that contain [CACHEDIR.TAG](http://www.brynosaurus.com/cachedir/) file, or to list all that don't. So far, I came up with

```sh
find ~ -type d -exec test -f {}/CACHEDIR.TAG ';' -print
```

and

```sh
find ~ -type d -exec test -f {}/CACHEDIR.TAG ';' -prune -o -type d -print
```

However, `test -f ...` feels a bit cumbersome and calling on every directory makes it painfully slow. For example, it takes over 30 seconds on my test directory, while plain `find ~ -type d` takes less than 1 second (tested after everything was cached into memory).

Anybody knows a better/faster solution?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in steps:

```
find ~ -type f -name CACHEDIR.TAG | sed -e 's/.CACHEDIR.TAG$//' a
find ~ -type d > b
grep -v -F -f a -x b
```